# Git repository enforce committer metadata

Tags: gitlab, git

The purpose is that I manage projects that may be distributed amongst multiple outsource agencies and we would like to, if possible, prevent them from knowing about each other by seeing the commit metadata of "User Name: email@agency.com" purely to avoid any potential political issues.

One method would be to force them to commit with an email address which conforms to a pattern i.e. "@mycompany.com" or could we rewrite the email address to confirm to that pattern?

Alternatively we could maintain 2 repositories and I or colleagues will be responsible for migrating commits between the 2 periodically, stripping out the committer metadata.

We're using GitLab currently to manage our repositories, although I can imagine such functionality could be dealt with in the pre-commit hooks?

Comment: have you found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018055/how-to-change-author-email-at-commit-time-with-hooks)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `pre-commit` hook to "warn" a user that they're committing with the wrong details, but there's no *guarantee* it will be run -- hooks aren't enabled by default on new clones (so people have to set them up themselves) and you can pass `--no-verify` to `git commit` to stop the `pre-commit` hook from running.  It's a nice thing to provide, and recommend, so that people are alerted as early as possible that their commit is bad, but it can't be used to *enforce* a requirement.

In order to *prevent* users from "publishing" their invalid changes, you need to use an `update` hook in the central ("integration") repo which checks all new commits being pushed, and rejects the entire push if any of the commits fails validation.  You'll also want to provide documentation (possibly in the push rejection message itself) about how to use `git filter-branch` to fix the invalid commits.